# Why does expansion sometimes echos the braces and sometimes don't?

Tags: bash

```
$ echo --hidden-import={a,b}
--hidden-import=a --hidden-import=b
```

as compared to

```
echo --hidden-import={$FILES}
--hidden-import={cpu_mon disk_mon mem_mon network_mon}
```

Where `FILES` was created by

```
export FILES=$(ls)
```

In the example I expected to get

```
--hidden-import=cpu_mon --hidden-import==disk_mon --hidden-import==mem_mon --hidden-import==network_mon
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion. If you have `{$x,$y}` the shell first processes it into two arguments `$x` and `$y`, and only then expands the variables within each argument separately. And if you have only one item, brace expansion doesn't happen at all; `{xy}` always remains just `{xy}`.

If you're writing for Bash, use arrays and parameter expansion instead:

```
files=(*)
echo "${files[@]/#/--hidden-import=}"
```

Here the `#` in `${var/#match/replacement}` makes it replace the (zero-length) matching string only at the beginning of the variable. Also note the usage of `files[@]` to get all elements of the array instead of just the first one.

If that doesn't work, just build the argument list using a loop:

```
args=()
for file in *; do
    args+=("--hidden-import=$file")
done
echo "${args[@]}"
```

Alternatively, Bash's printf can be used to add prefixes/suffixes to multiple arguments at once:

```
printf '--hidden-import=%s\n' * | xargs -d '\n' echo
```

In the worst case (if you have no Bash *and* you've ruled out all alternative CLI scripting languages such as Perl or Python or even PHP), try sed:

```
\ls | sed "s/^/--hidden-import=/" | xargs -d '\n' echo
```

*(Deliberate backslash to bypass aliases such as 'ls -F'.)*

Comment: The list (and order) of expansions can be found [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: Even if brace expansion happened after variable expansion, it requires the items to be separated by commas, and in his original code they're separated by spaces.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that works for standard `printf`, not just Bash's built-in version.

Comment: Brace expansion happens before variable expansion, _in Bash_. Zsh and Ksh are different. (Different from Bash, and different from each other...) I know, the question was tagged with [tag:bash], but the difference comes up sometimes (mostly in people asking why Bash does it that way).